# How do I change the color of the taskbar in Windows 10?

Tags: taskbar, colors, windows-10, desktop-customization

In earlier builds of Windows 10, this was possible from the Personalization -> Color and Appearance menu. However, "Color and Appearance" seems to have been removed from the final build. Is it still possible to change the taskbar color? How?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to change the color of the taskbar. It will change the color of the Start menu and action center as well though.

Right click on the desktop, then select **Personalize**.

[image: Personalize]

On the left side select **Colors**.

[image: Colors]

Turn **Off** *Automatically pick an accent color from my background* and then choose the color you want.

[image: Pick a color]

Now below that, turn **On** *Show color on Start, taskbar, and action center*.

[image: Turn on colors]

Voilà!

[image: Color taskbar]